# Problem displaying Image in Google Web App using Google Apps Script

Tags: image, display

Good day!
I am working on google web app using google apps script. The data of all employees such as id, name, position, station, file1 and file2 etc. are stored in google sheets. I want that file1 will display the employees image. The javascript code is

`{ targets: [7], //column 7 is column file1 className: 'dt-body-center', "render": function(data, type, row, meta) { if (type === 'display' && data.length > 20) { data = '<a href="' + data + '?text=' + row[7] + '" target="_blank">' + '<i class="fa fa-file" style="font-size:15px;color:black"></i>' + '</a>'; } return data; } },` 
Here's the additional details:
for the code.gs

`function globalVariables(){  var varArray = { spreadsheetId   : 'SHEET_ID', //** CHANGE !!! dataRange       : 'Data!A3:J',                                    //** CHANGE !!! idRange         : 'Data!A2:A',                                    //** CHANGE !!! lastCol         : 'J',                                            //** CHANGE !!! insertRange     : 'Data!A1:J1',                                   //** CHANGE !!! sheetID         : '0'                                             //** CHANGE !!!  }; return varArray; }`

var folder1 = DriveApp.getFolderById('FOLDER ID');//ganti fd dengan id folder

I tried to revise the javascript code like this:

`{ targets: [7], // column 7 is column file1 className: 'dt-body-center', render: function(data, type, row, meta) { if (type === 'display' && data.length > 20) { data = '<img src="' + data + '?text=' + row[7] + '" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">'; } return data; } },`

But I'm getting a broken image.

Any ideas how can I display the individual image of employees on the the web browser?

I tried to change the code but I'm getting to broken image

[[list of data displaying a broken image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPojo.png)]